# Проблемы с воспроизведением звука в тэге

Tags: jquery, html5

Уважаемые специалисты.

Нужна помощь по HTML5. Есть кусок кода с тэгом `<audio>`, написанный на jQuery, который при наведении мышкой на элемент, воспроизводит звук (звук имеет протяженность 1сек.), но при быстром движени мышью по элементам звук обрывается на половине и появляется еще какой-то звук щелчка. Это все смотрится некрасиво, точнее слышится некрасиво. Код такой

```
$('#nav ul li a').mouseover(function () {
    document.getElementById('empty_audio').innerHTML = '<audio autoplay="autoplay" id="audio" preload > <source src="sources/sound1.aac" /><source src="sources/sound1.ogg" />' + '<source src="sources/sound3.mp1" />' + '</audio>'
});
```

Пожалуйста, кто сталкивался с таким дебильным воспроизведением звука, прошу посоветуйте что-нибудь.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема в том, что аудио тэг у вас удаляется не успев доиграть до конца, возникает такой артефакт.

Вот один вариант. Добавляем элементы при наведении, ждем когда отыграет, удаляем.

```
var audioid=0;
$('#nav ul li a').mouseover(function () {
    document.getElementById('empty_audio').append( 
      '<audio id="audio_'+audioid+'" autoplay="autoplay" preload >'
      +'  <source src="sources/sound1.aac" />'
      +'  <source src="sources/sound1.ogg" />'
      +'  <source src="sources/sound3.mp1" />'
      +'</audio>');
    setTimeout($("#audio_"+audioid).remove(),10000);//лучше дольше, чем длительность звука
    audioid++; 
});
```

Второй вариант:

HTML:

```
<audio id="audio" preload >
  <source src="sources/sound1.aac" />
  <source src="sources/sound1.ogg" />
  <source src="sources/sound3.mp1" />
</audio>
```

JS:

```
$('#nav ul li a').mouseover(function () {
     audio = document.getElementById("audio");
     try {
       audio.currentTime = 0;
     }catch(e){
     };
     audio.play();
});
```

Comment: спасибо что откликнулись я потом попробую но пока я исправил тем что срезал в Nero 10 Wave editor сам звук до максимума и теперь не глючит